# Reducing a list of redundant conditions on strings

Tags: python

I have a list of conditions like the following:

```
conditions = [{"equals": "football"}, {"equals": "badminton"}, {"contains": "basketball"}, {"contains": "ball"}]
```

Some conditions are redundant:

- any string containing "basketball" also contains "ball".
- any string which is equal to "football" also contains "ball".

So the reduced list of conditions is the following:

```
conditions = [{"equals": "badminton"}, {"contains": "ball"}]
```

For the moment, I do something like this:

```py
TO_REDUCE = {("contains", "eq"): 0, ("eq", "contains"): 1, ("contains", "contains"): 1} # value is the index of the condition to keep
was_reduced = True
while was_reduced:
    was_reduced = False
    for i in range(len(conditions)-1):
        condition_1 = conditions[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(conditions)):
            condition_2 = conditions[j]
            operators = get_operators(condition_1, condition_2) # obtain for example ("eq", "contains")
            if operators in TO_REDUCE:
                kept_condition_index = TO_REDUCE[operators]
                kept_condition = (condition_1, condition_2)[kept_condition_index]
                del conditions[j]
                del conditions[i]
                conditions = [kept_condition] + conditions
                was_reduced = True
                break
        if was_reduced:
            break
```

I used the dict TO_REDUCE as there may be other operators as "starts by" or "ends by".

Is there a more efficient way to get the reduced list of conditions ?

Comment: Depending on what you're using this for, it might be easier to just filter out duplicates afterwards, rather than reducing like this.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I use the list to build SQL queries which are expensive. And the more conditions there are, the more exprensive the queries are. So I really need to reduce the list before.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it could be done much easier. I think you would achieve what you want by taking the words that should be contained, and removing conditions that contain any of them:

```
contains_words = [condition["contains"] for condition in conditions if "contains" in condition] # ["basketball", "ball"]

reduces_conditions = [condition for condition in conditions if not any([contains in condition.values()[0] and {"contains": contains} != condition for contains in contains_words])]
```

Comment: With the example given, the result is `[{"equals": "badminton"}]` whereas it should be `[{"equals": "badminton"}, {"contains": "ball"}]`.

Comment: I forgot that the condition can contain itself. I edited my answer to make it work.

Comment: It doesn't work neither: the conditions `[{"predicate": "eq", "value": "basketball",},{"predicate": "contains", "value": "basketball",}]` stay the same after reduction whereas `{"predicate": "eq", "value": "basketball",}` should not be kept.

Comment: @Rebecca you should update your question with a few more example inputs and their expected output so people can test before posting to avoid this edit-comment ping-pong